# How do I remove the permissions warning at the top of the login screen?

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

I have facebook authentication working, submitted my app and it has been approved, but I still see the error message when I login with Facebook.

[image: Permissions message that shows when I login]

I've reviewed the permissions I'm requesting and they are all covered by the approved permissions which you can see here:

[image]

I've cleared my cache, removed the app and tried re-login, but still the same response. Appreciate any thoughts on this or maybe it is a bug that I need to file with Facebook.

Comment: Which permissions are you asking for? You cut the screenshot so it is impossible to see

Comment: Are you sure it's the same app ID in the dialog as in the app settings, and that it's the exact same permissions?

Comment: @WizKid the one listed were all that I asked for: email, public profile, user_friends, and App Details

Comment: @Igy Confirmed it is the same app ID. I'm actually using a magento extension developed by a 3rd party. I reviewed the permissions with the developer and they said there should be no reason that it should show the message.

Answer (score 0):

This message is also not displayed to users of your app, It would only be displayed for admin or dev accounts. If you look in the "Items in Review" tab are there any pending items added to your submission.

Comment: I know it is only visible to me, but it is nagging as I don't understand why it is showing. I confirmed there are no pending items in the "Items in Review" screen.